# Push a pdf file on wiremock

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm using a wiremock standlaone service to mock several json Object.
Actually I want to mock a pdf file:  it works fine on my local by just adding my pdf to the __files folder

However I'm trying to use a POSTMAN (or curl) to push the pdf on the server and this doesnt work :

Here is my curl :

```
curl -X PUT https://wiremock-mock.myserver.com/__admin/files/Hello_World.pdf
-H 'Accept: */*'-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' 
-F pdf=@///usr/Perso/Downloads/Hello_World.pdf
```

I'm getting this error:

```
    HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /api/test/fichiers/111111. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:
wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@7adccef6:30:88: found: '?'
#???8FV?c?M8?+?J-P??????????GY???(|?6M:#????w]t???2?P?o?si????2??u?yD]F??$p?
?a????{{z???Z????q????5D&????j}??
??i?s??????{*?r?)5??ee???gzZ?-??kh?'??``Av?2?????(?????Q[????>yYn??iy???vj?f2O?u???gK_???@?7!?c??WF?Y??3$?u ?tT?k)???>??YE???0eX|?V?>?n?-????=?>??j?vB??;?????}2??e?mS?c?D?az??,^?ahV???^??G??R?????\??2?oTjD???G???3??|??9????vnz???&????????M??~?b???????????0???i[v?]?e?"????_????H1m??I?~à;?=???K?.????Ws????   c[?zW9?????]?E:,???????[?^?:????=?????9??V?DF??8?C??+"g$????J??\?nJ?
?Q??n?/?y?????NY?|??????L??3{??c??`C??????N??l??e?????-A??r?4??%???~i?-?????????9ZT!K?i?6)5R???1.????4??6?????  B?k2Z????P?6!$??????GFQ????ur?(??(??G?z???d??(????*???J??U??
?R"?b??I?Q?@??  mt??2d??= ????\?6??kO
                                                                                        ^

    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsErrorReporter.syntaxError(HbsErrorReporter.java:93)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParserFactory$2.notifyListeners(HbsParserFactory.java:148)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:144)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.fetch(BufferedTokenStream.java:169)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.sync(BufferedTokenStream.java:152)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.consume(BufferedTokenStream.java:136)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.consume(Parser.java:571)
    at wiremock.org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.match(Parser.java:203)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.sexpr(HbsParser.java:887)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.var(HbsParser.java:1381)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.statement(HbsParser.java:344)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.body(HbsParser.java:222)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParser.template(HbsParser.java:165)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsParserFactory$1.parse(HbsParserFactory.java:84)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.cache.NullTemplateCache.get(NullTemplateCache.java:54)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compile(Handlebars.java:475)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compileInline(Handlebars.java:435)
    at wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compileInline(Handlebars.java:415)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer.uncheckedCompileTemplate(ResponseTemplateTransformer.java:168)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer.transform(ResponseTemplateTransformer.java:122)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.InMemoryStubMappings.applyTransformations(InMemoryStubMappings.java:91)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.InMemoryStubMappings.serveFor(InMemoryStubMappings.java:72)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.serveStubFor(WireMockApp.java:167)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler.handleRequest(StubRequestHandler.java:50)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:47)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.service(WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:479)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How may I push a pdf file on the wiremock server ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to local response templating at startup using below command then it gives pdf.

```
java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar --local-response-templating
```

If you start wire mock with global response templating at startup, you will face the above exception.

```
java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar --global-response-templating
```

**Another working solution is:**

Use base64 body response for PDF like below.

```
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
    },
                "base64Body": "2wBDAAQDAwQDAwQE...=="       
            }
```